# I am sweating while lifting?

Tags: weightlifting, cardio, workout, sweat

I lift for an hr. and a half every other day... I have noticed that as I get further in(after 1 hr. of lifting I am breaking a sweat...) my face turns red and I sweat. Should this occur with weights? I thought it was solely cardio.

Comment: This is a trick question, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal to sweat while lifting weight, especially if you do compound lifts like squats and deadlifts, it also depends heavily on the temperature in the room. I sweat a lot more in the summer.

The reason why you sweat is to maintain your body temperature at around 37 degrees, when you use energy in any way, you will be pushing your temperature upwards, meaning you have to compensate with sweat to keep it steady.

Running usually uses more energy than weight lifting, but when you run, you get a greater cooling effect because the air is typically colder than you are, meaning you won't sweat as much as you might think you would.